# My HTML form is not mailing the results to me

Tags: html

I have made and html file following the books Computer Learning by Sumita Arora and it's Cornestone
class 7. I have been making a form using chapter 7, and it's not working!  The full code is (the wrong line is the mailto: line)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>


<title>A Form</title>


</head>


<p>A Form</p>



<body style="background-color:grey">


<form action = "mailto:email address blured for obvious reasons" method = "post">

<p>
<b>First name:</b>
<input type = "text" id = "firstname" style="background-color:black"><br/>
<p><b>Last name:</b>
<input type = "text" id = "firstname" style="background-color:black"><br/></p>
<p><b>School:</b>
<input type = "text" id = "School" style="background-color:black"></br></p>
<p><b>Address</b>
<input type = "text" id = "Address" style="background-color:black"></br></p>
<input type = "submit" value = "Send" style="background-color:black"> <input type = "reset" style="background-color:black">
</br>
Copyright &copy; Manik Sharma (THEOP05) 2022
</p>



</form>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is a bit invalid. You have nest `<P>` tags,

Comment: Your form elements do not have name attributes.

Comment: yes, but that's what the book says! thx, btw but pls just ans my que if u know the ans

Comment: I am telling you things that are wrong. Form uses name to submit things, id is not used. Invalid html causes browser to guess at your layout. The `<b>` tags really should be `<label>` elements. I could go on and on. The book has problems if that is what they wanted you to type out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailto` does not send an email in an automated way. It instructs the user's browser to *show* the user an email client. When I run your code on my local machine, the "Submit" button pops open Mozilla Thunderbird, since that's the email client installed on my machine. If you don't have an email client installed on your machine, then it's possible nothing will happen.

Of course, that's the *client's* machine, which is very likely not what you want. If you really want your form to send an email with the form results to `THEOP05@example.com`, you need to do that routing on the server side. The details will depend on your server framework (Django, Rails, PHP, etc.), but you should add an ordinary HTTP endpoint on your server, something like `http://example.com/form-submit`, which takes the form input as a POST parameter and, using whatever language your server is written in, sends the email server-side.

I know Django has facilities for automating the handling of forms (and conventions in place to make it easier). I suspect Rails does as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the method to "get"

```
<form action = "mailto:email address blured for obvious reasons" method = "get">
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to send email with a form, you need an email delevery service. In the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), Html is the view (frontend) and sending email should be done by the controller or the model (backend). I like to use [mailgun](https://mailgun.com/), but any other large scale email delevry service will provide you a nice UI and multiple usefull features. If your backend is PHP, you can use composer to install dependencies. I recommand the [symfony mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html) `composer require symfony/mailer` with you favorite 3rd Party Transport (eg.: `composer require symfony/google-mailer` for gmail.)

­> Note that if your backend directly send emails, thoses emails can go into spam pretty much every time, and it takes a lot of ressoruces to process the email delevery, but this is a decision you can take based on how you want to send your emails.